# Creating a Silverlight, drag & drag enabled query builder

Tags: silverlight, drag-and-drop, telerik

what would be the best components to create a query builder? I imagine I'll need some sort of grid control. 30x30 cells perhaps. I would also love to have a snap-to-grid functionality as well. I'll be parsing the contents of the grid to create the queries so if I can iterate through the cells it would be a great help to. I'd be more than happy to post a sample project for anyone else to use if you all could help me with the base requirements. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using the Telerik components for Silverlight, what about the RadExpressionEditor or RadDataFilter don't fit the requirements for what you're looking to do?  Just curious as they are meant to handle this type of scenario.

ExpressionEditor allows for typing, which may not be the ideal if you're looking for a less error-prone scenario (aka, you don't trust users to write queries):
http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#ExpressionEditor/FilteringGridView

Otherwise DataFilter lets users select options based on the items and their respective types found in your collection, so it is much harder for a difficult user to break ;D :
http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#DataFilter/FirstLook

Is neither of those fit the bill, can you post more info in regards to your scenario/what you're looking to accomplish (and why you're looking at a 30x30 grid setup for the basis) and we might be able to brainstorm something good up. :)

-Evan